# In a team of 2 people (one front end, one scripting), is there any way I could write scripts without the use of Unity all together?

Tags: unity, teamwork, workflow

So, I'm curious whether or not it would be possible to write scripts for a Unity game without using Unity itself, but using a third-party IDE, such as Visual Studio. My reason for this would be the following: I have a very low-end laptop, so I can not run Unity in any usable fashion. So I'm wondering if I could do the programming only part for the game without using Unity? By this, I mean writing the actual code and sending it over some online platform to be integrated with the Unity environment. And I know, this would not be productive at all.

Comment: Visual Studio is already the standard IDE for writing Unity code, so it's unclear what you anticipate might prevent you from doing this. What technical hurdle have you encountered when trying to write Unity scripts this way?

Comment: No, the main point is: Can I write the scripts without using Unity itself, only Visual Studio and then send them for testing and implementation over the Web? (I know, sounds very unproductive)

Comment: Scripts are just text files, so I"m struggling to understand what you think could possibly make this *not* work. You could author that text file in literally any method you could think of, notepad, writing out the binary by hand, etc., and at the end of the day Unity wouldn't be able to tell the difference because it's still just a text file. It has no idea where the file was authored, in what program or on what computer. Did you actually try it before asking?

Comment: You can even create your own .dll libraries for unity (just find and add to references UnityEngine.dll) and pack almost whole game into them. In that case you can send .dll for testing and not worry about someone reading your source code. If you're writing a _very_ good code, you'll almost never need to open Unity, but in real world frequent testing (both with Unity and written tests) speeds development a lot.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So if I got your question correct, you don't want to open Unity but write the scripts that would work on it?

You **CAN** but you might not be sure about what you've written since it can not be tested without opening Unity. You might even solve syntax errors using intellisense (Visual Studio have intellisense for these) but if there's any logical error, calculation mistakes that you might've made, you will have to open up Unity to debug.

Since scripts are simple text files, you can write it on any IDE you want to, but testing will definitely require opening Unity.

Answer (score 0):

You may write those scripts but you'll be unable to test and debug them without opening unity.

Comment: _How_ would they do that?

Comment: So my idea would be possible, just very unproductive?

Comment: Unity console provide an interface to show game related error u double click on them it take your to the error where it is located and also what if a logical error occur You will never debug them without using unity editor

Comment: No i think it is not. An idea is an idea Its is not a question of productive or unproductive. You ask You learn dude

Comment: I mean I could have access to screenshots of said error, I just can't use Unity itself, that is my only issue. So I would act kind of like a tech support guy when it comes to those.

Comment: So u have a low end computer Can i know about your specification?>

Comment: @AliRaza did you mean "**unable** to test and debug without unity"? The word "enable" in this context confused me.

Comment: @AliRaza The reason is kind of irrelevant... It could be that there is one Pro licence and they don't want to pay for another one.

Comment: unable..........